# Every finitely generated group has simple quotient

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I've read that every finitely generated group has a simple quotient. Is it obvious?

Comment: Well it's not true for the trivial group. Otherwise it is an application of Zorn's lemma: if $G$ is not simple then it has a nontrivial normal subgroup that does not contain one of the generators $x$. Consider a normal subgroup that is maximal subject to not containing $x$, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to conclude from this, but I wrote a solution. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes your solution is more or less what I had in mind.

Comment: @DerekHolt Probably YCor would have been along soon to point out that Zorn’s Lemma isn’t needed. To save him the trouble, I’ll point out his comment on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324763/non-hopfian-groups-that-only-have-quotients-that-are-themselves-or-the-trivial

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for the pointer! But I think the proof that finitely generated groups have maximal subgroups needs Zorn's Lamma.

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn’t the same (choice free) proof work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a finite set of generators of $G$.

Let $n$ be the largest number such that there is a normal subgroup $H\subsetneqq G$ containing $n$ of these generators.

The set of all such $H$ satifies the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma, and has a maximal element $H$. Now if $H \subsetneqq K\trianglelefteq G$,then $\# K\cap X > n$ and $K = G$ by definition of $n$.

$G/H$ is a simple group